# Implementation of Port scan in Python

Tags: python

I have a program that scans for open ports on remote host.
It will take long time to complete the scan.I want to make it work fast.

Here's my code:

## Port Scan

```
import socket
import subprocess

host = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(host)

print("Please wait, scanning remote host", hostIP)

try:
    for port in range(1,1024):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((hostIP, port))
    if result == 0:
        print("Port: \t Open".format(port))
        sock.close()
```

Could one of you Python wizards help me with this.
Advance Thanks.

Comment: Is this a project or do you just want to scan from python, if so there is python-nmap which will do what you want

Comment: No sir, I'm learning Python and i found this program while checking few examples and i wanted to try this.

Comment: How long does it take to run for you?

Comment: Python program seems very interesting to me. I am keen interested to learn more things on my own.

Comment: 3 to 4 hours to complete the full scan

Comment: How many ports are you scanning exactly?

Comment: 1 to 1024, system ports. I guess i have given the range at the right place in program?

Comment: I can scan 50k ports in about a second

Comment: run this http://pastebin.com/Y4ikn7iU using localhost

Comment: Can i please know how to do that?

Comment: I posted a link which uses your own code, not sure what you have done with your own but there is no way it should take hours

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give a try and get back to you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: does not work how? did you run it on 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: I don't know why? Yes i did it on localhost.

Comment: what output did you get?

Comment: There was no output for long time and now there is one shown. I guess it is working fine but the process is slow.

Comment: Are you running the code against a remote host or locally?

Comment: i running it against locally

Comment: The reason why it takes so long as well is because you are waiting for the reply of each port. Why not multithread it? If you multithread it you can check multiple ports at the same time!. I made a multithreaded port scanner before, also using a queue, ill post it asap.

Comment: Multi threading? Ya i will give a try with that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on the socket so it wont spend to much time on a closed port. I would also use threads and allow the user to specify how many threads they want to run. here is a link to some code you could adapt to implement threading with the threading module [Python Network Programming.](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/threadingmodule.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
A simple port scanner.
'''

import socket

def scan_host(host, **options):
    '''
    Scan a host for open ports.
    '''
    options.setdefault('timeout', 0.30)
    options.setdefault('port_range', (1, 1024))
    timeout = options.get('timeout')
    port_range = options.get('port_range')
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    print("Please wait, scanning remote host {} : {}".format(host, host_ip))
    for port in xrange(*port_range):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(timeout)
        result = sock.connect_ex((host_ip, port))
        if result == 0:
            print "Port: {} Open".format(port)
            sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scan_host('www.google.com', timeout=0.30, port_range=(1, 8000))
```

Comment: why are you using setdefault when get takes a default argument, better still why not use `timeout=0.30` as a keyword

Comment: Hey Ricky, Thank you so much. That really  helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This program became too simple. It monitors only one port at once and it takes long time on one port to see if it is listening. So try reducing the time to listen, if it can't connect, deem it to be closed by setting a recursion limit for that number under the "expect:" in run().

As in like this,

```
            try:
                # connect to the given host:port
                result = sock.connect_ex((hostIP, port))
                if result == 0:
                    print "%s:%d Open" % (hostIP, port)
                    sock.close()
            except: #pass
                sock.recurse += 1
                if sock.recurse < sock.limit: 
                    sock.run()
                else:
                    print "%s:%d Closed" % (hostIP, port)
```

There is other way to make it much more efficient by importing threading() module which can be used to keep an eye on a large number of sockets at once.

Here's the document on threading.

Refer this,
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#

Hope that helped you.
All the best.

Comment: `return = sock.connect_ex((hostIP, port))`?

Comment: Also what are `sock.recurse`, `sock.limit` and  `sock.run()`?